# FOL axiom scheme: if A, then (if B, then A)

Tags: logic

Why is this scheme needed, and how is it different than the obviously incorrect saying, "if a conclusion is true, then any premise implies/entails the conclusion."

Comment: See [Structural rule: Weakening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_rule): in a sense, it formalizes the "obvious" fact that we can add unnecessary premises.

Comment: We may say: "if a conclusion is proved from some premises, then any additional premise can be added in the proof of the conclusion."

Comment: I don't understand the contents of the link, and I'm not sure if you're using the word premises since you're trying to relate to the words I've used in the question. But it's very confusing since it seems that premises are only premises in relation to the conclusion, yet you speak of unnecessary premises. And it's surprising that it holds a place as the first FOL axiom scheme.

Comment: The "obviously incorrect saying" is correct and does say the same thing as your title, i.e. true conclusion follows from any premise. Why? Because an implication is only false when its premise is true and conclusion is false, which, obviously, cannot happen when the conclusion is known to be true.

Comment: Can you take this to Math.SE where a qurstion of mathematical logic belongs.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belomgs on Math.SE - mathematical logic.

Comment: @Conifold Would you say follows/implies/entails means validity?

Comment: @CSP: Is this the conifold who called me "suspicious" by use of Gadamers *Hermeneutics of Suspicion* by any chance? If Conifold had suspicions about me let him spell it out properly in words. If he has the courage.

Comment: @Conifold: Can you tell me what you meant by hoisting Gadamer's book, *The Hermeneutics of Suspicion* over my head all those years ago? What were you getting at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a terminological issue here. Your formula would be written as

`A ⊃ (B ⊃ A)`

in classical FOL, where ⊃ is the material conditional. This is indeed a tautology of the classical propositional logic, which can be demonstrated easily, e.g. by using truth tables. In some axiom systems, it serves as an axiom.

It is important not to refer to the conditional as 'entails'. The material conditional is a connective within the object language. P ⊃ Q is equivalent to ¬P ∨ Q, and also to ¬(P ∧ ¬Q). In other words, it is simply a truth function: it takes two truth values as arguments and returns a truth value as its result. Entailment, on the other hand, is a meta-level relation between two sentences that expresses the fact that the first logically entails the second, or equivalently, that the second is the logical consequence of the first. This is a much stronger relation, and is more commonly expressed as P ⊨ Q. In model-theoretic terms, P ⊨ Q holds iff P ⊃ Q is true in all interpretations.

To use the word 'implies' is also potentially misleading. 'Implies' is notoriously ambiguous in English. John Corcoran wrote a paper identifying more than a dozen different uses of the term in logic. Some people use 'implies' to mean the material conditional, which is also known as material implication. Others use it to mean entails, but as I pointed out above, it cannot be both. On the whole, it is a confusing term and is probably best avoided.

If you were to express an argument as follows:

```
A
____

B ⊃ A
```

This argument is valid in classical FOL, since the truth of A is sufficient for the truth of B ⊃ A. But you would be right to observe that if a conclusion is true, then it is not the case that any premise *entails* the conclusion, since that would amount to

```
A
_____

B ⊨ A
```

This does not hold in all interpretations.

Comment: Thanks. So, would a conclusion that's true in all interpretations, such as A or not A, be ENTAILED by any premise?

Comment: Yes indeed. This is sometimes called the principle of implosion, or by the latin expression ex quodlibet necessarium sequitur. It is actually the flip side of the more familiar principle of explosion.